# How to call php script from C code on Linux

Tags: php, c, linux

just wanted to know how to call php script from running C code on Linux and pass a couple of parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
system("/usr/bin/php /path/to/program.php param1 param2");
```

Comment: You should rather advice the use of execlp() or something like it, for security reasons.

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable answer to the question that was asked.  There was no mention of any mistrust of the script or data passed to it.